# What is the best (rather easiest) way to move newly imported objects to the location of the old ones?

Tags: python, import

So here is the code I'm using to import objects and then move them to the location of the objects that have the same name:

```
import bpy
import os

folder = 'path'

# placing the origin of the existing objects to geometry
bpy.ops.object.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )
bpy.ops.object.origin_set( type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY' )

# list of locations (vectors)
locs = []

# importing .dae files and renaming them
for ob in bpy.data.objects[:]:
    name = ob.name
    names.append(name)

    # ad hoc solution for naming while debugging
    if '.001' in name:
        name = name[:-4]

    locs.append(ob.location)
    path = os.path.join(folder, name[10:] + '.dae')
    obj = bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=path)
    path = ''

    # iterating over newly imported objects
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        obj.name = name
        obj.data.name = name

bpy.ops.object.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )
bpy.ops.object.origin_set( type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY' )
```

I want to move the newly imported objects where the old ones are. This is needed to be done after the last 2 lines (since before them the newly imported objects have their origin set differently than the old ones). How can I do that?

Comment: `locs` is a list, `obj` is a `bpy_types.Object`, which can't be used as a list index. This is ultimately a Python, not Blender question. `obj.location = ob.location`

Comment: Thanks for the remark. The old question was ill-posed, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the question is to put

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set( type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY' )
```

inside the main for-loop after the import command.